# How Do I Open an SQLite3 Table in Ruby That is Read from an S3 Object

Tags: ruby, sqlite, amazon-s3

So I am trying to read an SQLite3 database I have stored on S3.

I can fetch and read the file and get its raw innards that look like:

```
puts dbdata
????????etable1t#sample textTABL#sample text1 in#sample textvarc#sample text         #sample text   #sample text    #sample text
 => nil
```

but if I try to create an SQLite3 object in ruby out of this, it does not have my table.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
db = SQLite3::Database.open(dbdata)
```

So I can query the object. Really lost here, does anyone know how to create an SQLite3 db from the files contents, not the file itself? I'd like to try and avoid downloading the file each time the script runs.

Comment: I'll highly recommend using [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) to work with the database. It's a great ORM, which makes it easy to use SQLite databases. The next thing that is great about Sequel, the code you write to work to the SQLite database is very portable to other DBMs so there's little rework or wasted effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need all the content of the database to use it. So, what's the problem with downloading it?

There is no way around it.

Comment: cool thanks. Going in another direction I guess. Still would be awesome to have that ability.

Comment: If you need that you probably want an hosted database instead of sqlite.